# MacVim: Re-map command key combinations like <d-f>

Tags: macvim

I can remap unused combinations like `<d-1>` (Cmd+1) in MacVim, but there are many combinations like `<d-f>`, `<d-o>` or `<d-b>` that are already bound to MacVim menu items.  If I try to remap those inside my .vimrc, nothing changes.

Is there some way I can remap those combinations inside MacVim, or stop MacVim from assigning them to menu items so they are properly passed on to the Vim core?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found it: [Command-T](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T) recommends using the following snippet:

```
if has("gui_macvim")
  macmenu &File.New\ Tab key=<nop>
  map <D-t> :CommandT<CR>
endif
```

So basically you unmap the respective menu item, and then you are free to map the shortcut you were trying to map.  (I'm not sure what the ampersand is doing; it works with and without it.)

This **must** be put in ~/.gvimrc, not ~/.vimrc!  (Apparently ~/.vimrc is read too early, so the (un)mappings will be clobbered if you put them there.)

Comment: I tried this on the current version of MacVim (7.3) and it didn't work.  I ended up going into $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim, searching for `<D-` and putting a `&& 0` at the end of the surrounding if statement.  Then I copied the contents to my .gvimrc and replaced `<D-[^>]*>` with `<nop>`.

Comment: @dash-torn-bang Hm, my code above seems to still be working OK with 7.3 snapshot 62 on Lion. I didn't have to edit MacVim's menu.vim. I'm not sure why it's working for me but not for you...

Comment: I was able to get it to work without ampersand: `macmenu File.Print key=<nop>`

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. Though with a slight modification: `macmenu File.Close key=<nop>`